# How to use patch request with body json in node?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, request, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to connect with mongodb cluster using MongoDB atlas api to modify cluster. For authentication, it uses digest auth and to modify cluster I have to use patch request with body json to pass paused value in json body. I'm using node script to trigger the pause.

Can anyone help with this? Please feel free to ask away any details needed.

Comment: got it working by applying header to use JSON. Do closing this.

Answer (score 0):

got it working by applying header to use JSON. Do closing this.